# How to re-run process python in Windows/Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

I run Python script on Windows using IDE PyCharm.

Sometimes process is stopped. How can I configure that process will be re-run automatically after interruption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also 3 ways as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014300/3545745) answer.

1 way create infinity batch loop

```
:loop
python your_script.py
goto loop
```

2  and 3rd way are already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014300/3545745).
Also you can start python script as windows service but it much harder.