# How to re-run process Linux after crash?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, centos

I have Python script, that is run from Linux(Cent OS).

How can I run this process(script) forever? Or such as it will be re-run after crash?

Comment: Do you want restart it from python?

Comment: you need to show us something.

Comment: I have script file: `index.py` I need to re-run this after it crashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 way bash script

```
while true;
do
    python index.py 
done
```

2 way start python script

```
import os
while True:
    os.system("python index.py")
```

3 way from external python script  `import index.py` and then start external script.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special variable *$?* which contains the value returned by process. It equals zero if process exits normally. You can use it in bash script to re-run your process after crash. Create file *rerun.sh* in the folder contains *index.py*:

```
#!/bin/bash    
t=1
while [ $t -ne 0]
do
   python index.py
   t=$?
done
```

And make it executable:

```
chmod +x rerun.sh
```

Run your bash script to re-run your python script after crash:

```
./rerun.sh
```